# How to display hover info on a plotly Table?

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to display hover info over a plotly Table.  This is my best guess, but no hover text shows up in a jupyter notebook or when the figure is exported to html and viewed in a browser:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

hover_text = [['hover a', 'hover b', 'hover c'],
              ['hover d', 'hover e', 'hover f']]

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    cells={'values': [['a', 'b', 'c'],
                      ['d', 'e', 'f']]},
    hoverinfo='text',
    meta={'text': hover_text}
)])

fig.show()
fig.write_html('test.html')
```

plotly version 4.5.4

There are a number of go.Table() parameters that seem like they may be relevant, but I have not found a combination that displays anything:

- hoverinfo
- hoverinfosrc
- hoverlabel
- meta
- metasrc
- customdata
- customdatasrc

Some references I've been looking at:

- https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Table.html
- https://plotly.com/python/table/
- https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#hover-labels
- https://plotly.com/python/reference/#table

Answer (score 1):

It seems like its a documentation bug and hovers are currently not working with tables. You can check out the open git issue regarding this error:
https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/5523