# How to load HTML table into Plotly hover...?

Tags: python, html, plotly

I've been trying to implement an HTML table into my graph label, I have one column in my df with the html code but it isn't showing in the right format. Does anyone knows how can I change this?

[plotly code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVEGh.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NRwr.png)

if you hover the cursor in the graph you will see something like:

```
table border=1 class="dataframe"><thead><tr style="text-align: right;"><th>Index</th><th>Place name</th><th>Qtd</th><th>AVG</th>
```

Comment: Please add the entire code and a sample of the dataframe to tge question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display hover info on a plotly Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62539208/how-to-display-hover-info-on-a-plotly-table)

Comment: Thanks, but not really. I already have the table formated in html code and I need to put in hoverlabel. I can't show you the dataframe because it contains sensitive information, sry.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at this time it's impossible to render a table in the way that I intended. They are planning to make a future update where it will be possible.